# extract entry of a vector or Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, extract, subset

i have this matrix

```
> dist
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7
1 0.00 0.52 0.34 0.37 0.37 0.52 0.54
2 0.52 0.00 0.77 0.57 0.57 0.00 0.56
3 0.34 0.77 0.00 0.29 0.29 0.77 0.53
4 0.37 0.57 0.29 0.00 0.00 0.57 0.32
5 0.37 0.57 0.29 0.00 0.00 0.57 0.32
6 0.52 0.00 0.77 0.57 0.57 0.00 0.56
7 0.54 0.56 0.53 0.32 0.32 0.56 0.00
```

I WANT TO extract the row number 1 but since the third position
`0.34 0.37 0.37 0.52 0.54`

i try with `dis[1,>=3]`  but there is a error

Comment: You should provide the code that you tried and the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a sequence for the columns to select with `[`:

```
dist[1,3:7]
```

Comment: Or `dist[1,-c(1,2)]`, if you don't want to mess with the number of columns